# Deep Learning - Does there exists a network that only allows flow from input A or B?

Tags: deep-learning

So let's say I input A and B both with output size 5. The let's say I have a gated network that's of size 10 and takes in both A and B. Does there exists a gated network that will set the weights of the neurons associated with input A to 0 and input B to 1 based and vice versa based on some condition? Put another way does there exists a neural network that can use certain inputs for some cases and never for others in a binary way? Similar to a network flow problem. So in some cases it should allow flow from A only and other cases only B.

Comment: It's pretty hard to follow what you're asking. Giving some examples or some code would help a lot. Alternatively, this may not be programming question, have you considered asking on Cross Validated instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing, the network is context agnostic, so it cannot guess when to use each input, it would be neccesary to include a previous step to choose A or B. Another approach is adding an additional input for context information so the weights could be trained in order to give a good result using both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want the network to decide which input to use or not. In case there are some known rules, just apply them and zero out the unwanted data before feeding them into the net. But I guess you want the other option.

In that case, you could start your network with two branches. Each branch would be fed with one of the inputs. The branches would merge at some point and the output would be two neurons with Gumbel-softmax activation function (so you can backpropagate through it). There would be two residual connections from inputs A and B, connected to the rest of your network. But the first residual connection would be multiplied with the output of the first Gumbel neuron and the second residual connection would be multiplied with the output of the second Gumbel neuron. If the first neuron is 0, or close to 0, the other will be 1 or close to 1. So it would be some kind of gate you asked for.

Disclaimer: I have no personal experience with Gumbel-softmax, I've just read about it [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/differentiable-argmax/33020/11). So please think critically about this solution and check yourself if it works. I am unable to sit behind a PC to code it and try it right now.

Comment: @Gooby did you try it?